# How to determine if a SMTP transaction is inbound or outbound?

Tags: smtp

I was wondering how to distinguish inbound from outbound SMTP transactions.

Normally this would be a straightforward question, however my SMTP server has to handle a special case:

- Other domains might point to my MX domain (mail address aliases)

What outbound criteria should I check for?
Is it as simple as checking if the transaction is authenticated (via the AUTH command), or do any other rules apply (derived from the FROM/RCPT addresses)?
I guess alias addresses can be detected by resolving their MX?

Comment: The side that sends the first TCP packet with the SYN flag set is who determines if it is inbound or outbound.  Some more context here would have made this a better question.

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm talking about SMTP not TCP. A SMTP connection can be inbound or outbound (relay) regardless of your SYN flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sender is in your domain, it's outbound.

If the recipient is in your domain, it's inbound.

If neither are in your domain, it's relay, and drop it like a hot potato.

Comment: What if both are in my domain?

Comment: Then it's entirely local.

Comment: I guess I'm just over-thinking this...